# install4jc specifying floating server

Tags: install4j

I now that with install4jc i can spefic the floating server and version (windows or multiplatform) in the command line.

Is is possble to specify these in any of the install4j configuration files installed on our build server so that folks do not have to remember to set them on each and every build plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the installation directory to set the floating license server for all users on a machine:

Take the file `%USERPROFILE%\.install4j5\config.xml` or `$HOME/.install4j5/config.xml` and copy it to `[install4j installation directory]/config/config.xml`.